# How to spatially smooth data on a map?

Tags: r, cartography, ggplot2

I've been struggling a lot lately to produce a map in R with the ggplot2 package. So far this is the map I managed to achieve (where each little plygon stands for a city) :

[image]

The data used for this map is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/g0sbtst597qtkcl/AABLry1hLLiusSwbu3PEZMvia?dl=0), the code used for this map is:

```
#require 
library(ggplot2) 
library(rgdal)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

#open df
data = read.table("datafr_comm.txt", header=T, sep="\t", quote="", dec=".", colClasses=c(rep("factor",)))
data$score <- as.numeric(as.character(data$score))

#open shapefile 
mapa <- readOGR(dsn="France",layer="codes_postaux_region")
mapa <- spTransform(mapa, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
#prepare for merging dataframe/shapefile by ID
mapa@data$id <- rownames(mapa@data)
mapa@data   <- join(mapa@data, data, by="ID")
mapa.df     <- fortify(mapa)
mapa.df     <- join(mapa.df,mapa@data, by="id")
#merge dataframe/shapefile
plotDatafr <- left_join(mapa.df, data)

#plot map
ggplot() +
geom_polygon(data = plotDatafr, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "white", colour = NA) +
geom_polygon(data = plotDatafr, aes(x=long, y = lat, group = group, fill=item), colour = NA) + 
scale_fill_manual(values = c("#009E73", "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7"), name = "") + 
coord_map()
```

Now, I can't figure out a way to fill automatically the white zones on the map by calculating an average of the surrounding points. I tried many things including the `stat_density_2d` or `stat_bin2d` functions, but no way to achieve what I really want.

Comment: I'm aware of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10047870/plotting-interpolated-data-on-map) but could not adapt it on my own problem...

Comment: Is this some sort of discrete classification? So there's no interpolation possible? Do you just want to assign each unknown region to one of the categories? I can't think of a statistically rigorous way of doing it without a complex multivariate spatial model. Plenty of ad-hoc methods spring to mind, like building an adjacency graph and using a colouring scheme based on majority neighbours or something... Either way its *not* a heatmap and its *not* smoothing (unless interpolation is possible).

Comment: @spacedman I m more looking for an ad hoc solution since this is kind of a discrete classification (values are assigned to each region).

Comment: So would setting the missing values to the value of the nearest non-missing value be okay?

Comment: If you just want the map to "look nice", you might consider some "photoshop" style display filters instead of trying to get R to generate something?

Comment: @spacedman yes I think that it would work fine!

Comment: It also looks like you need dplyr, plyr, and rgdal loaded for your code to work - I don't know why you've got `rgeos` there.

Comment: @Spacedman my mistake: i edited the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the "assign value of nearest non-missing value by centroid distance" solution.

I'll use a simpler data set so you can see what's happening.

```
require(raster)
require(spdep)
columbus <- shapefile(system.file("etc/shapes/columbus.shp",package="spdep"))
```

To which I'll add a `THING` column which is a factor with a lot of missing data. Set the seed for reproducibility:

```
set.seed(310366);columbus$THING = as.factor(sample(c("A","B","C",NA,NA,NA,NA),49,TRUE))
spplot(columbus,"THING")
```

[image: original data with missing values]

Now I need the `FNN` package for nearest neighbours. I'll then calculate the nearest neighbours of the centroids of the polygons with missing `THING` to the ones with non-missing `THING`:

```
require(FNN)
srcs = coordinates(columbus)[!is.na(columbus$THING),]
dsts = coordinates(columbus)[is.na(columbus$THING),]
nn = get.knnx(srcs, dsts, 1)
```

Now `nn$nn.index` is an index into the *non-missing* `THING` values, so I can fill in the missing things with a lookup into the missing things. Like this:

```
columbus$THING[is.na(columbus$THING)] = columbus$THING[!is.na(columbus$THING)][nn$nn.index]

spplot(columbus,"THING")
```

[image: nearest-neighbour fill in]

To use this correctly, make sure your geospatial data is on a metric coordinate system, so before you project to lat-long. You should probably also wrap it up into a nice function.

```
fillin <- function(shapes, name){

    srcs = coordinates(shapes)[!is.na(shapes[[name]]),]
    dsts = coordinates(shapes)[is.na(shapes[[name]]),]
    nn = get.knnx(srcs, dsts, 1)

    shapes[[name]][is.na(shapes[[name]])] = shapes[[name]][!is.na(shapes[[name]])][nn$nn.index]
    shapes
}
```

Then you can just do:

```
 columbus = fillin(columbus, "THING")
```

Here's your french data (plotted with `spplot` rather than faffing around with `ggplot`, so different colours):

[image: before and after]

This was done on `mapa` just after the `data` is joined to it, and without doing an `spTransform`.